# I can't seem to access my home web sever?

Tags: apache-http-server, xampp, hosting

So I installed XAMPP and went to localhost on my web-browser and I get the XAMPP page, all seems well. I then went on no-ip and created a host: yoursite.no-ip.com. I went into my router settings to forward port 80 on the default gateway address and downloaded their dynamic IP software and added the host I created. I also made sure apache was running and that the conf file was listening on port 80 and the server was specified as yoursite.no-ip.com:80. When I try to go to yoursite.no-ip.com on my browser it just spins for a second and then tells me it could not connect. Anyone know what I am missing here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Usually port 80 is blocked by ISPs. Try using port 8080 or something off the wall.

Googling I found this tool to check to see if ports are blocked: http://www.canyouseeme.org/

Comment: I tried switching to 8080, but still got same thing. Using that site I got the following error on port 80: "Reason: No route to host"

Answer (score 1):

What you could do that works great is that if your router allows you to forward ports to other ports, like the name implies, you can open another port besides the common web ones that your ISP blocks. Some ISPs have the ports open but supply routers that otherwise won't. Try forwarding port 80 to something else, then make apache listen to that something else.

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply, the domain name points to your public ip, which isn't accessible from inside your network.

You can test this a few ways - see if you can access the website with [tor](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en) or other proxy, or check if its up with [is it down for everyone or is it just me](http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/).

Also try accessing the web server using the server's internal/lan ip address.

If either of these work, you could just add a hosts entry for your domain name to access it.

Comment: I went onto my VM_Ubuntu and used Tor to try and access that site and it still failed to connect?

Comment: how about using the ip address of the system within the lan?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, how would I do that?

Comment: well, find out the ip address of the server. then type in http://<ipaddress> in a web browser

Comment: Oh yes, I already tried that a number of times...I think I am just going to give up, it's not worth it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Oh, then there *is* something wrong with your setup. Wouldn't happen to have skype installed by any chance would you?